# Is there a way to get an asset compiled on every request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm having an issue where I have an asset containing dynamic content. Say for instance time.js.erb that looks like:

```
var time = "<%= Time.now %>";
```

My problem is that since I don't change the asset, the asset won't be compiled instead I get "304 Not Modified" in response and the time var will be the same as in the last request.

Is there a way to instruct the asset pipeline to always compile the asset, at least when in development?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with Date/Time just use javascript Date class for that.

Comment: Yes, of course. The real case is that I want to generate test fixtures for my JS unit tests, and using asset pipeline would be really great.